# Rails Active Model Serializer not showing correct attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, can anyone point me in the right direction?  I set up the initializers and the associations in the model but my JSON is still returning only the attributes inside Active record, including the created_at and updated_at attributes.  What am I doing wrong?

ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  include ActionController::Serialization



  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render nothing: true, status: :forbidden }

    end
  end
end
```

CompanyController.rb

```
def show
  @logo = Logo.find(params[:user_id])
  render json: @logo
end
```

CompanyModel.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :logo, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy

end
```

LogoModel.rb

```
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

CompanySerializer.rb

```
module V1
    class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :user_id, :name

      has_one :logo
    end
end
```

LogoSerializer.rb

```
module V1
    class LogoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
        attributes :id, :company_id, :image_url


    end
end
```

EDIT:  I should have posted the CompanyController Action, not the LogoController.  I've added it above and added the LogoSerializer

Comment: Can you please explain what behavior you are hoping to accomplish and what the current behavior is with examples?

Comment: I'm expecting the JSON rendered by the controller action to be the attributes listed in the Company Serializer and incidentally, the Logo Serializer.

Comment: I think the error is because you're rendering the logo and not the company object. Also could you post your logo_serializer?

Comment: I was mistaken, I should have shown the action I was using inside the company controller.  Only the attributes listed in the serializer should be be rendered, but it's rendering all the attributes in Active Record and none of the attributes from the LogoSerializer.

Comment: Have you tried removing the LogoSerializer from the V1 module?  I think the model and it's corresponding serializer have to be in the same namespace.

Comment: There's actually an open issue on active-model-serializers about version control and the recommendation was to make the serializer a subclass.  I did try removing it though and it didn't change anything.